# How to change image save path in CkEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

In Django CkEditor, when you upload an image to the server, it is stored in the path that is written in settings.py CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH. And then it saves year/month/day/file along the way.
Is it possible to change this path depending on the application and model?
For example, if I am writing an article in the "info" application, and the article will have its own "slug", then it will be saved at:
*media/info/some_info/photo.png*
Now, it turns out:
*media/2023/05/11/photo.png*
Or at least do:
*media/info/some_info/2023/05/11/photo.png*

This is the last thing I tried to do:
def ckeditor_upload_path(instance, filename):
return 'uploads/{}_{}/{}'.format(instance.slug, instance.id, filename)